# Variable dispatch is not defined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

I'm getting an anoying error while triying to dispatch a custom Event.

What I'm triying is this:

1- Setting a listener in a .as file.

```
import flash.events.Event;

emisor.addEventListener("accionTerminada", onAccionTerminada)

function onAccionTerminada(evento:Event):void{
    trace("Accion Terminada");
}
```

2- Launching the event in another .as

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("accionTerminada"));
```

But I don't know why I'm getting the following error

> ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable dispatchEvent is not defined.

Don't know why its passing dispatchEvent as a variable instead of a function...

Also tried dispatch having the same error.

Thanks

EDIT:
 The other .as.
    public class CustomPalManager implements IProvideCustomPalList, IManageCustomPal {

```
    [Inject]
    public var space:CurrentSpaceCustomPal;

    private var _collection:VectorCollection;


    public function remove(target:CustomPalVO):void {
        var index:int = space.value.content.indexOf(target);
        if (index != -1) {
            space.value.content.splice(index, 1);
            collection.refresh();
            //dispatchEvent(new Event("updateAfterDelete"));
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentError("Impossible to remove wall, it doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not enough information, show this `other .as` that is actually throwing the error. Best guess: it doesn't inherit from an EventDispatcher class.

Comment: Ok, edited the post with the other .as

Comment: Also I think you are right, the element I'm using doesn't inherit from that class.

Comment: Bingo, your class should extend `EventDispatcher` or one of its many many children `Sprite`, `MovieClip` etc. That's where the `dispatchEvent` gets defined, your class simply inherits the function.

Comment: Thank you, it was the error message messing with me.